# swiftyJSON check if value is null

Tags: ios, swift, swifty-json

I have a json which is array of dictionary

```
response.text = [{
"id": "4635465675",
"name": "Arts",
"pluralName": "Arts",
"shortName": null
}]
```

`json = JSON((response.text)?.data(using: .utf8))`
How can i check is value for key "shortName" null or not, say for first dictionary in the array ?
I tried to do like this

```
if json[0]["shortName"] is NSNull
```

But it's always true.
How can i handle it?

Comment: try this `if json["shortName"] is nil` . or `if let shortName = json["shortName"]  { print("shortName - \(shortName)") } else { print("shortName is nil") }`

Comment: if let  _  = json["shortName"] as? String {
   // it is not null
}

Comment: @AshwinShrestha didn't worked

Comment: `json[0]["shortName"] is NSNull` **But it's always true. How can i handle it?** off course it will be true because its null

Comment: @Krunal didn't worked too

Comment: Try this.

    if let name = Json.first?.["shortname"] {

}

Comment: @AamirR but before it i got IF doesn't it make any difference ?

Comment: @ShauketSheikh nothing :(

Comment: Your code is `if json[0]["shortName"] is NSNull { SHORT NAME IS NULL } else { NOT NULL }`, its a working code

Comment: @Michael - Show your full json response and how do you store it into variable `json`

Comment: but your json is a dictionary say [String:String], not array of dictionary  objects [[String:String]], so i dont know why you are trying to access the first element of json using the index[0]

Comment: @Krunal full json  `[{
    "id": "4635465675",
    "name": "Arts",
    "pluralName": "Arts",
    "shortName": null
}]`
and json variable 
`var json = JSON((response.text)?.data(using: .utf8))`

Comment: @AshwinShrestha full json `[{
    "id": "4635465675",
    "name": "Arts",
    "pluralName": "Arts",
    "shortName": null
}]`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

you can directly check as the key of `JSON.null`

```
if json[0]["shortName"] == JSON.null {
// show the alert

}
```

if its your String

```
if json[0]["shortName"].string == nil {
```

Comment: YES, that's was exactly what i needed. THANKS

Comment: shouldn't `if json[0]["shortName"].stringValue == nil{` change to `if json[0]["shortName"].stringValue == ""{` as stringValue always returns String not String?

Comment: @WimukthiRajapaksha- thanks for your comment , we can also use like `if let getShortName = json[0]["shortName"].string,!getShortName.isEmpty {
            print(getShortName)
        }`

Answer (score 0):

Execute following code and see

```
let jsonArray = [{ "id": "4635465675", "name": "Arts", "pluralName": "Arts", "shortName": null }] 

if let jsonObject = jsonArray[0] as? [String : Any] {

    if let id = jsonObject["id"] as? String {
       print("id - \(id)")
    } else {
       print("id does not exist or it is null/nil")
    }

    if let name = jsonObject["name"] as? String {
       print("name - \(name)")
    } else {
       print("name does not exist or it is null/nil")
    }

    if let pluralName = jsonObject["pluralName"] as? String {
       print("pluralName - \(pluralName)")
    } else {
       print("pluralName does not exist or it is null/nil")
    }

    if let shortName = jsonObject["shortName"] as? String {
       print("shortName - \(shortName)")
    } else {
       print("shortName does not exist or it is null/nil - \(jsonObject["shortName"])")
    }


}
```

Share here result of this code.

Comment: Error: initializer for conditiobal binding must have Optional type

Comment: all lines returned "does not exist or it is null/nil"

Comment: Exact ouput for this line - `print("shortName does not exist or it is null/nil - \(jsonObject["shortName"])")` ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that's was easier than i was thinking

```
if json[0]["shortName"].string == nil {
//null
}else{
//not null
}
```